# PHP Uploading Multiple files always gives me timeout error

Tags: php, file, request-timed-out

Ok, I don't quite understand why, but no matter what I seem to set in PHP's ini_set function, I am unable to upload multiple files or the files that I'm uploading are too big...  I don't understand it.  Here's what I am setting so far within the script that handles the `$_FILES[]` array that is being uploaded when posting the form:

```
// Try and allow for 3 hours, just in case...
@set_time_limit(10800);

// Try and set some ini settings to buy us some time...
@ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
@ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '512M');
@ini_set('post_max_size', '550M');
@ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '10800');  // Allows for up to 3 hours
@ini_set('max_input_time', '10800');  // Allows for up to 3 hours
@ini_set('max_execution_time', '10800'); // Allows for up to 3 hours
```

I am using `move_uploaded_file` to place it into the specified directory, not sure if that matters or not?

Honestly, how can I allow multiple files to be uploaded without a TIMED OUT ERROR??  If I upload 1 file, seems fine.  Not sure if it's a quantity problem with multiple files or the combined files are just too big in filesize?  Have tried with like 15MB total filesize, and this produces a TIMED OUT ERROR!  arggggg!!!!

What must I do to make this work??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an apache server, the server itselfs has a timelimit too.

Look at the TimeOut directive at apache configuration (by default is 300 seconds)

You can look at the apache error log too

If you upload only 2 files ok 1Kb each, works fine?

Comment: How do you check the apache error log?  and/or look at the `TimeOut` directive at apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

For uploading large + multiple files reliably you should use file uploaders

I prefere http://www.uploadify.com/ for this